# Create a star and give a background color using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to draw a star and give it a background color by using Javascript. This is the jsfiddle :-

http://jsfiddle.net/earnubs/TZasK/

But red background color is covering whole sqaure area, I just want to give background to that star only.

This is the Javascript :-

```
var canvas, ctx, length = 15; // length of the star's arm

// grab a reference to the 2d context from canvas element
canvas = document.getElementById("star");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// move into the middle of the canvas, just to make room
ctx.translate(30, 30);

// initial offset rotation so our star is straight
ctx.rotate((Math.PI * 1 / 10));

// make a point, 5 times
for (var i = 5; i--;) {
    // draw line up
    ctx.lineTo(0, length);
    // move origin to current same location as pen
    ctx.translate(0, length);
    // rotate the drawing board
    ctx.rotate((Math.PI * 2 / 10));
    // draw line down
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    // again, move origin to pen...
    ctx.translate(0, -length);
    // ...and rotate, ready for next arm
    ctx.rotate(-(Math.PI * 6 / 10));
}
// last line to connect things up
ctx.lineTo(0, length);
ctx.closePath();
// stroke the path, you could also .fill()
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: I know you're using canvas, but coincidentally, I had a similar issue today and ran across this awesome thread: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/TZasK/464/

Use `ctx.fillStyle = "#f00"` after ctx being defined and `ctx.fill()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Add using `fillStyle` and don't forget to add `fill()` after `fillStyle` or it won't work.

```
ctx.lineTo(0, length);
ctx.fillStyle = "#f22";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.strokeStyle='red';
      ctx.fillStyle='blue';
      ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```